# Store hex color value in variable and convert it into JPEG in PHP

Tags: php

I have passed the hexacolor value in merge.php and store it into the variable
now. i want to convert the hexacolor value into the jpeg using php.
so what should i do.here is my code.

```
$bgcolor = $_POST['clickcolor']; // clickcolor store hexacolor like #4c1130
echo $bgcolor;
$im = imagecreate(640, 480)or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $bgcolor);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($im);
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to make an image with a plain colour? Why not just create a `div` of the required size and set CSS `background-color` on it?

Answer (score 1):

`imagecolorallocate` requires four parameters, the first one the resource, then integers between 0 and 255 or hexadecimals between 0x00 and 0xFF.

**Description**:

```
int imagecolorallocate ( resource $image , int $red , int $green , int $blue )
```

**Examples:**

```
$im = imagecreate(100, 100);

// sets background to red
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

// sets some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// hexadecimal way
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
```

[Check the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:
Use the function hexColorAllocate from hex to desired.

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
      $png_image = imagecreate(150, 150);
      hexColorAllocate($png_image, '4c1130');
      imagepng($png_image);
      imagedestroy($png_image);


      function hexColorAllocate($im,$hex){
        $hex = ltrim($hex,'#');
        $a = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
        $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
        $c = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
        return imagecolorallocate($im, $a, $b, $c); 
    }
```